# Crash when launching a new Activity from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I get an error when launching an activity from a fragment, using an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),FormActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("Horas",hours);
intent.putExtra("Minutos",minutes);
intent.putExtra("Segundos",seconds);
intent.putExtra("Fecha",date);
intent.putExtra("Hora",time);

startActivity(intent);
```

LogCat:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1719)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1491)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3436)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3393)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
at es.timetrack.app.InActivityPageFragment.onClick(InActivityPageFragment.java:148)
```

Comment: Have you declared it in manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Declare** the `Activity` you are starting in the **Manifest .xml** file:

```
<activity
      android:name="your.package.FormActivity"
      android:label="FormActivity" />
```

Some additional information:
[**The App Manifest**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

There you can see the **structure** of the manifest.xml file and what it is **used for**.

In addition to you not declaring your `Activity` in the manifest file, your application might crash due to **unhandled exceptions** in the `onCreate(...)` method of your `FormActivity`.